# CherryPy sessions for same domain, different port

Tags: python, session, cherrypy

Consider the script below. It will launch two subprocesses, each one a CherryPy app (hit Ctrl+C or whatever the KeyboardInterrupt combo is on your system to end them both). If you run it with CP 3.0 (taking care to change the 3.0/3.1 specific lines in "StartServer"), then visit:

http://localhost:15002/

...you see an empty dict. Then visit:

http://localhost:15002/set?val=10

http://localhost:15002/

...and you see the newly populated dict. Then visit:

http://localhost:15012/

...and go back to

http://localhost:15002/

...and nothing has changed.

If you try the same thing with CP 3.1 (remember the lines in "StartServer"!), when you get to the last step, the dict is now empty. This happens in Windows and Debian, Python 2.5 and 2.6.

You can try all sorts of things: changing to file storage, separating the storage paths... the only difference it makes is that the sessions might get merged instead of erased. I've read [another post](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/bcae0fe34ad4cbcb/53f31a360f9b8cf7) about this as well, and there's a suggestion there to put the session tools config keys in the app config rather than the global config, but I don't think that's relevant to this usage where the apps run independently.

What do I do to get independent CherryPy applications to NOT interfere with each other?

Note: I originally asked this on the [CherryPy mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/8492771209e70381) but haven't had a response yet so I'm trying here. I hope that's okay.

```
import os, os.path, socket, sys
import subprocess
import cgi

import cherrypy

HTTP_PORT = 15002
HTTP_HOST = "127.0.0.1"

site1conf = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : HTTP_HOST,
        'server.socket_port' : HTTP_PORT,
        'tools.sessions.on' : True,
#        'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file',
#        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '1',
#        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '.',
        'tools.sessions.timeout' : 1440}}

site2conf = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : HTTP_HOST,
        'server.socket_port' : HTTP_PORT + 10,
        'tools.sessions.on' : True,
#        'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file',
#        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '2',
#        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '.',
        'tools.sessions.timeout' : 1440}}


class Home(object) :

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """\
<html>
<body>Session:
<br>%s
</body>
</html> """ % cgi.escape(str(dict(cherrypy.session)))

    @cherrypy.expose
    def set(self, val):
        cherrypy.session[self.key.upper()] = val
        return """\
<html>
<body>Set %s to %s</body>
</html>""" % (cgi.escape(self.key), cgi.escape(val))

def StartServer(conf, key):
    cherrypy.config.update(conf)

    print 'Starting server (%s)' % key
    cherrypy.tree.mount(Home(key), '/', {})

    # Start the web server.
    #### 3.0
    # cherrypy.server.quickstart()
    # cherrypy.engine.start()
    ####

    #### 3.1
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
    ####

def Main():
    # Start first webserver
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen(
        [sys.executable, os.path.abspath(__file__), "1"])
    proc2 = subprocess.Popen(
        [sys.executable, os.path.abspath(__file__), "2"])

    proc1.wait()
    proc2.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print sys.argv

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        # Master process
        Main()
    elif(int(sys.argv[1]) == 1):
        StartServer(site1conf, 'magic')
    elif(int(sys.argv[1]) == 2):
        StartServer(site2conf, 'science')
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie, where session identifier is stored, is bound to host, not host+port. When you visit the first site you get new session id **in 3.1 (but not in 3.0)**, then you fill session data and can see it. After that you go to other port with this session id, but now it's invalid (I believe you can see this in log in debugging mode). So the server send you new session id. Now you return to first server and again your identifier is invalid so you get new one. Sure, there is no data in the session in for this new identifier.

**Update**: RFC 2109, section 4.3.1  Interpreting Set-Cookie says:

> The user agent keeps separate track of
>   state information that arrives via
>   Set-Cookie response headers from each
>   origin server (as distinguished by
>   name or IP address and port).

But interpretation of standard is not so obvious. Here is a cite from the related [ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142803#c28) in firefox tracker:

> There are two RFC for cookies, 2109
>   (For set-cookie) and 2965 (For
>   set-cookie2)
>
> In RFC 2109  in section 4.3.1
>   Interpreting Set-Cookie it states
>   "Domain Defaults to the request-host.
>   " And in section 2 TERMINOLOGY it
>   states   "The terms request-host and
>   request-URI refer to the values the
>   client    would send to the server as,
>   respectively, the host (but not port)
>   and    abs_path portions of the
>   absoluteURI (http_URL) of the HTTP
>   request line.    Note that
>   request-host must be a FQHN."   In RFC
>   2965 in section 3.3.1 Interpreting
>   Set-Cookie2  it states   "Domain
>   Defaults to the effective
>   request-host. " it also states   "
>   Port    The default behavior is that a
>   cookie MAY be 
>               returned to any request-port. " And in section 1
>   TERMINOLOGY it states   " The terms
>   request-host and request-URI refer to
>   the values the client 
>       would send to the server as, respectively, the host (but not port)
>   and 
>       abs_path portions of the absoluteURI (http_URL) of the HTTP
>   request line. "   (Just like RFC 2109)
>
> My interpretation of these is that
>   port numbers should not be used for
>   recording cookie domains unless a
>   set-cookie2 header explicitly defines
>   port number.

Comment: So... does that mean there is no solution? It's not possible to differentiate the two sites in CherryPy? I figured that since it works in 3.0 but not in 3.1, something has changed that I could change back (at the API level, not by hacking on the core).

Comment: By the way, I suspect that they're wrong about differentiating based on name as well, but I'd have to check it out.

Comment: According to the links above there is no reliable way to make it working in all browsers without switching to Set-Cookie2 header which has Port parameter.

Comment: I'll have to see if it's possible to get the CherryPy tools.session module to use that header.

Comment: I've updated the answer with difference in CherryPy 3.0 and 3.1 behavior. Although it should be considered as bug in 3.0, you might modify a local copy of 3.1 to get it back.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see *anywhere* except the tests that "Set-Cookie" is used. There's some weird magic going on somewhere. Wonderful.

Comment: Set-Cookie is used in the standard Cookie module.

Comment: This may give me enough information to sort things out, and even if it doesn't I appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Change the CherryPy config parameter `tools.sessions.name` to something unique to each application.

**Long answer**:

I know this is a very old question, but I think there is a very simple answer. Writing below for the benefit of future searchers.

CherryPy uses a cookie to find sessions. By default, this is called "session_id" and has a random hexadecimal string as its value. If CherryPy is given a session_id that it doesn't recognise, it generates a new session_id. This is a measure to prevent session fixation.

When you have two applications on the same domain. They both use the same cookie name (i.e. "session_id"), but neither recognises the session_id of the other and so they overwrite it with a new one. So moving from one application to the other invalidates the session.

The solution is simple: In the CherryPy configuration, you can override the session_id name by setting `tools.sessions.name` to something other than "session_id", for example "myapp_session_id" and "myotherapp_session_id".

You need to make sure the session storage is separate as you've correctly identified.

From the example above, you'd do something like this:

```
site1conf = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': HTTP_HOST,
        'server.socket_port': HTTP_PORT,
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file',
        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '/tmp/site1_sessions/',
        'tools.sessions.name': 'site1_session_id',
        'tools.sessions.timeout': 1440
    }
}
site2conf = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': HTTP_HOST,
        'server.socket_port': HTTP_PORT + 10,
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file',
        'tools.sessions.storage_path': '/tmp/site2_sessions/',
        'tools.sessions.name': 'site2_session_id',
        'tools.sessions.timeout': 1440
    }
}
```

Note: In my own apps using CherryPy 10.0.0, I've used this config option at the app level and at a path level. I haven't tested this with old versions of CherryPy, but looking at the source code, it looks like it's been possible for over a decade.

Since writing this, I've contributed an update to CherryPy's documentation about this, included here: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html#session-fixation-protection